# golang -- Initializing Project Variable

Tags: variables, go, initialization

I am a golang beginner and I have a package level variable:

```
var yellow color.RGBA
```

I want to initialize it in a function so I do this (no compiler warnings):

```
func setColors() {
    yellow = color.RGBA{R: 0xff, G: 0xff, B: 0x00, A: 0xff}
}
```

If I do this in my function, I get a "Unnamed field initialization" compiler warning:

```
yellow = color.RGBA{0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff}
```

But my project-level variable allows me to do both of these:

```
var yellow = color.RGBA{0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff}
var yellow = color.RGBA{R: 0xff, G: 0xff, B: 0x00, A: 0xff}
```

Why can I omit the field names (R, G, B, A) in the project-level initialization but not in the function?

**24-Jan Update -- Complete Code Example**

This is where my variable initialization problem is happening.

This application displays a dynamic lissajous figure in a web browser. 
The lissajous line color is yellow.

You need to start the app with a command line parameter **web**
After starting the app, open a browser and point it to http://localhost:8000/

Line **reference #3** (func setColors(), end of code sample) is supposed to set the yellow variable (**line reference #2**). Line reference #3 is where I get the "Unnamed field initialization" compiler warning.

When I run the app as is **from within Intellij**, var yellow does not get set and the lissajous figure does not get drawn correctly in the browser.

However if I use line **reference #4** instead of **#3**, the application works fine.

**Line reference #1** works fine, but I need to know why **reference #3** is not working.

```
// Copyright © 2016 Alan A. A. Donovan & Brian W. Kernighan.
// License: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/

// Run with "web" command-line argument for web server.
// See page 13.

// Lissajous generates GIF animations of random Lissajous figures.

package main

import (
    "image"
    "image/color"
    "image/gif"
    "io"
    "math"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "time"
    "net/http"
    "log"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "strconv"
)


var palette = []color.Color{color.Black, yellow }
var red color.RGBA= color.RGBA{0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff}
var green color.RGBA = color.RGBA{0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff}

// Line reference #1
//var yellow = color.RGBA{R: 0xff, G: 0xff, B: 0x00, A: 0xff}

// Line reference #2
var yellow color.RGBA

var blue color.RGBA = color.RGBA{0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff}

const (

    whiteIndex = 0 // first color in palette
    yellowIndex = 1 // next color in palette
)

func main() {
    // The sequence of images is deterministic unless we seed
    // the pseudo-random number generator using the current time.
    // Thanks to Randall McPherson for pointing out the omission.
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())
    setColors()
    if len(os.Args) > 1 && os.Args[1] == "web" {
        handler := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            lissajous(w, r)
        }
        http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8000", nil))
        return
    }
    lissajous(os.Stdout, nil)
}

func lissajous(out io.Writer,  r *http.Request) {
    const (
        //cycles  = 5     // number of complete x oscillator revolutions
        res     = 0.001 // angular resolution
        //size    = 100   // image canvas covers [-size..+size]
        //nframes = 64    // number of animation frames
        //delay   = 8     // delay between frames in 10ms units
    )
    // Get query parameters
    cycles  := getQueryParameterFloat("cycles", r, 5)
    size := getQueryParameterInteger("size", r, 100)
    sizeFloat := float64(size)
    nframes := getQueryParameterInteger("nframes", r, 64)
    delay := getQueryParameterInteger("delay", r, 8)

    fmt.Println("cycles type:", reflect.TypeOf(cycles))
    freq := rand.Float64() * 3.0 // relative frequency of y oscillator
    anim := gif.GIF{LoopCount: nframes}
    phase := 0.0 // phase difference
    for i := 0; i < nframes; i++ {
        rect := image.Rect(0, 0, 2*size+1, 2*size+1)
        img := image.NewPaletted(rect, palette)
        for t := 0.0; t < cycles*2*math.Pi; t += res {
            x := math.Sin(t)
            y := math.Sin(t*freq + phase)
            img.SetColorIndex(size+int(x*sizeFloat+0.5), size+int(y*sizeFloat+0.5),
                yellowIndex)
        }
        phase += 0.1
        anim.Delay = append(anim.Delay, delay)
        anim.Image = append(anim.Image, img)
    }
    gif.EncodeAll(out, &anim) // NOTE: ignoring encoding errors
}

// getQueryParameter returns the value of a parameter in the query string.
// If an error occurs, the function returns the default value passed in.
func getQueryParameterFloat(name string,  r *http.Request, defaultVal float64) float64 {


    v := r.URL.Query().Get(name)

    v2, err := strconv.ParseFloat(v, 64)
    if err != nil {
        return defaultVal
    } else {
        return v2
    }
}

func getQueryParameterInteger(name string, r *http.Request, defaultVal int) int {
    v := r.URL.Query().Get(name)

    v2, err := strconv.Atoi(v)
    if err != nil {
        return defaultVal
    } else {
        return v2
    }
}


func setColors() {
    // Line reference #3 When I use this, the application does not function correctly
    yellow = color.RGBA{0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff}        

    // Line refernce #4 When I use this, the application **does** function correctly.
    //yellow = color.RGBA{R: 0xff, G: 0xff, B: 0x00, A: 0xff}

}
```

Comment: It compiles for me. Can you post a minimal example (i.e., a whole file) that exhibits the problem?

Comment: [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org) provides a nice sandbox for creating such examples. eg: Here is a working example of what you have described https://play.golang.org/p/u6Vbm90SLP

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting this error? If this is in Intellij with go-idea plugin. Then this has been recently fixed as you can see [here](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/issues/2267).

Comment: Yes, I'm using Intellij with the go-idea plugin. That might explain why others can run the code and not get errors. I'm trying to figure how to post my complete sample to the go playground as someone else requested (or alternatively, add my code to my original post).

Comment: Are you using the same version of intellij go plugin where the issue is fixed.? You can check my answer for the link.

Comment: The plugin version is 0.13.1924

Answer (score 0):

**Just tried your question out with the following code:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "image/color"
)

var yellow color.RGBA

func main() {
    fmt.Println(yellow)
    setColors()
    fmt.Println(yellow)
}

func setColors() {
    yellow = color.RGBA{R: 0xff, G: 0xff, B: 0x00, A: 0xff}
}
```

**With the output:**

```
{0 0 0 0}
{255 255 0 255}
```

It seems to be working for me, I'm not sure if I wrote my code differently to yours.

Comment: @Andy Schweig I've updated my original post with the complete application where the problem is occurring, along with an explanation. I didn't explain my problem very well. I experience the error when I use yellow = color.RGBA{0xff, 0xff,  0x00, 0xff}